# ReactJS: How to avoid the re-rendeing the whole page if only one part is changed?

Tags: reactjs

I have a page and part of it should be rerendered depending on a variable.

What I'm doing now is:

```
renderPart(){
  const partComponent = (this.state.part == 0 ? <div>1</div> : <div>2</div>);
  return partComponent;
}
render(){
   return (<div>{this.renderPart()}</div>);
}
```

Every time when this.state.part is changed it's called the render function. How to make it call *only* renderPart function? I'm open to using any other approach but I can't figure out which it could be.

Comment: You may have to show us more code, but I would venture a guess that you need to make your components more granular.

Comment: As suggested by @larz , divide your code into more meaningful components, then you might not face such issue.

Comment: That article is lovely for you: Pure functional components in React 16.6
 https://blog.logrocket.com/pure-functional-components-in-react-16-6/, it's a hardly 30 mins read, but you'll have a load of good things from it.

Comment: @SultanH. I tried to extract renderPart() into Pure component but I have the same result - main component's render is called every time when this.state.part is changed - maybe because now I'm passing the state variable into that child component as a props?

Comment: @larz I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give some example of "more granular" code?

Comment: @mimic, the state will always cause the `render` function to execute, if you want to control which of the components in `render` should, or shouldn't re-render, you'll need to make the Pure Components changes at all of them -or sanely just the big ones-

Answer (score 2):

So, since your state is on the component level, every time you have a state change, the entire component will be re-rendered.

I think a good approach to solve that would be to separate this `renderPart` function in a **new component with its own state**. That way, when you have a state change, only the `render` function of this new component will be triggered.

If you need to share state between components, I recommend you to use `redux` to make it simple, maintainable, and efficient. Its better than pass states and functions to change it by `props` to low level components.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about using redux but had a hope it can be done easier way :) Let me try this approach.